# Output difference between ipython and python

Tags: python, ipython, read-eval-print-loop, repr

It was my understanding that python will print the `repr` of the output, but this is apparently not always the case.  For example:

In ipython:

```
In [1]: type([])
Out[1]: list

In [2]: set([3,1,2])
Out[2]: {1, 2, 3}
```

In python:

```
>>> type([])
<type 'list'>
>>> set([3,1,2])
set([1, 2, 3])
```

What transformation does ipython apply on the output?

Comment: ipython `1.1.0` on python `2.7.5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `repr` or standard `pprint` module IPython uses `IPython.lib.pretty.RepresentationPrinter.pretty` method to [print the output](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html#IPython.lib.pretty.RepresentationPrinter).

Module `IPython.lib.pretty` provides two functions that use `RepresentationPrinter.pretty` behind the scenes.

`IPython.lib.pretty.pretty` function returns the string representation of an object:

```
>>> from IPython.lib.pretty import pretty
>>> pretty(type([]))
'list'
```

`IPython.lib.pretty.pprint` function prints the representation of an object:

```
>>> from IPython.lib.pretty import pprint
>>> pprint(type([]))
list
```

IPython uses its own pretty printer because the standard Python `pprint` module "does not allow developers to provide their own pretty print callbacks."

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that `IPython.lib.pretty.pretty` is indeed the function which is used?  I did `IPython.lib.pretty.pretty = lambda *args, **kwargs: 'potato'` and there was no change in the output within ipython.

Comment: @wim, good catch, I've edited my answer. `IPython.lib.pretty.RepresentationPrinter.pretty = lambda *args, **kwargs: sys.stdout.write('12')` will print 12 for any input.

Comment: note that this is only the case if the `%pprint` magic is ON. I have it turned off by default, and get the behavior the OP is seeing at the regular Python prompt.