# When I am in the Python or IPython console, what is called when I am returned an output?

Tags: python, ipython

For example,

```
python
>> x = 1
>> x
1
```

I'm curious about what method/function on `x` is returning 1. I'm asking because I'm seeing differences between calling `print x` and simply `x`.

Similary, is there a way to specify what is called? Does this configuration exist in IPython?

Comment: I think you're asking about the difference between [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). Each one returns a string that describes an object, but they don't always return the same result.

Comment: It probably comes down to that - but which is being used in the above case?

Comment: doing a local test, looks like `repr`

Comment: Yeah. Short answer: `print` uses `str`, and `>> x` uses `repr`.

Comment: Wanna make that an answer?

Comment: Ok, I'll put something together real quick...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/544342) for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you inspect an object in that manner in a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), it invokes the object's [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method. In comparison, `print` uses the object's [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method. Example:

```
>>> class Widget:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "repr of a Widget"
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "str of a Widget"
...
>>> x = Widget()
>>> x
repr of a Widget
>>> print(x)
str of a Widget
>>> print([x,2,3])
[repr of a Widget, 2, 3]
>>> print(repr(x))
repr of a Widget
>>> print(str(x))
str of a Widget
```

When defining `__repr__` and `__str__` for your own classes, try to follow the documentation's suggestions regarding which one should be more detailed and "official".

> [`__repr__` computes] the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).
>   ...
>   [`__str__` computes] the “informal” string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object. This method differs from `object.__repr__()` in that there is no expectation that `__str__()` return a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation can be used.

Comment: Worth noting that if `__str__` isn't defined, `print(x)` returns x.__repr__()`

Comment: The answer by @wim should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer addresses `repr` in a vanilla Python REPL, but it neglected to answer about IPython, which [works quite differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21110915/674039) and has many more features (and complexity) in regards to REPL printing.

Here's an example discrepancy:

```
# vanilla python:
>>> type([])
<class 'list'>

# in IPython:
>>> type([])
list
```

IPython has a [custom pretty printer](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/lib/pretty.py) and public hooks for customizing repr within IPython. One such hook is `_repr_pretty_` (single underscores!) and here's a basic example:

```
>>> class Widget:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         "vanilla"
...     def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
...         p.text("chocolate, strawberry")
...         
>>> Widget()
chocolate, strawberry
```

For more features, see "*Integrating your objects with IPython*" in the docs, in particular the [**Rich display**](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html?highlight=_repr_pretty_#rich-display) section.