# Tell IPython to use an object's `__str__` instead of `__repr__` for output

Tags: ipython, repr

By default, when IPython displays an object, it seems to use `__repr__`.

`__repr__` is supposed to produce a unique string which could be used to reconstruct an object, given the right environment.
This is distinct from `__str__`, which supposed to produce human-readable output.

Now suppose we've written a particular class and we'd like IPython to produce human readable output by default (i.e. without explicitly calling `print` or `__str__`).
We don't want to fudge it by making our class's `__repr__` do `__str__`'s job.
That would be breaking the rules.

Is there a way to tell IPython to invoke `__str__` by default for a particular class?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304092/when-i-am-in-the-python-or-ipython-console-what-is-called-when-i-am-returned-an

Comment: The "usual" solution, as far as I'm aware, is to just write a weird `__repr__`. Pandas dataframes do that, for example.

Comment: @user2357112 Awww :-(

Comment: Similar to [python - How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is certainly possible; you just need implement the instance method `_repr_pretty_(self)`. This is described in the [documentation for `IPython.lib.pretty`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html). Its implementation could look something like this:

```
class MyObject:
    def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
       p.text(str(self) if not cycle else '...')
```

The `p` parameter is an instance of [`IPython.lib.pretty.PrettyPrinter`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html#IPython.lib.pretty.PrettyPrinter), whose methods you should use to output the text representation of the object you're formatting. Usually you will use `p.text(text)` which just adds the given `text` verbatim to the formatted representation, but you can do things like starting and ending groups if your class represents a collection.

The `cycle` parameter is a boolean that indicates whether a reference cycle is detected - that is, whether you're trying to format the object twice in the same call stack (which leads to an infinite loop). It may or may not be necessary to consider it depending on what kind of object you're using, but it doesn't hurt.

---

As a bonus, if you want to do this for a class whose code you *don't* have access to (or, more accurately, don't want to) modify, or if you just want to make a temporary change for testing, you can use the IPython display formatter's `for_type` method, as shown in [this example of customizing `int` display](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993580/56541). In your case, you would use

```
get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(
    MyObject,
    lambda obj, p, cycle: p.text(str(obj) if not cycle else '...')
)
```

with `MyObject` of course representing the type you want to customize the printing of. Note that the lambda function carries the same signature as `_repr_pretty_`, and works the same way.