# How to implement _repr_pretty in a Python mixin?

Tags: ipython, mixins, repr

Following this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453624/tell-ipython-to-use-an-objects-str-instead-of-repr-for-output), I tried to include `_repr_pretty` in a mixin.

Without the mixin, it works as expected:

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "The Repr."
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "The str."
...     def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
...         p.text(str(self) if not cycle else '...')
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> my_object
The str.
```

But if I move the `_repr_pretty` into a mixin, it does not work anymore:

```
>>> class MyMixin:
...     def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
...         p.text(str(self) if not cycle else '...')
>>> class MyClass(MyMixin):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "The Repr."
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "The str."
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> my_object
The Repr.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's not a bug, it's a feature... It is explained here:

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10959,
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/452.

In summary, when you write your own `__repr__` in a subclass, it takes precedence over a `_repr_pretty_` of a parent class. The philosophy behind it is that in that kind of case, you typically want your custom `__repr__` method to be used by the IPython pretty printer also.

Here is a possible workaround:

```
>>> class MyMixin:
>>>     def _my_repr_(self):
...         raise NotImplementedError
>>>     def __repr__(self):
...         return self._my_repr_()
>>>     def _repr_pretty_(self, p, cycle):
...         p.text(str(self) if not cycle else '...')
>>> class MyClass(MyMixin):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
...     def _my_repr_(self):
...         return "The Repr."
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "The str."
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> my_object
The str.
```