# What attributes are used when returning an instance of the object in ipython?

Tags: ipython

In an ipython terminal, suppose I create an object and then just type the object's name and hit return, what attributes/methods of that object (and in what order) are queried to produce the output that is returned to the screen?

E.g.,

```
In [1]: from mymodule import myclass
In [2]: C = myclass()
In [3]: C # hit return
Out[3]:
```

What attributes/methods of C are queried to produce the output in `Out[3]`?

**Update**: From the answer (and also a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304092/when-i-am-in-the-python-or-ipython-console-what-is-called-when-i-am-returned-an) that I found, it shows that `__repr__` is called. However, I have a class that defines `__repr__`, but it doesn't appear to be being used and I get the following traceback error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
244             self.start_displayhook()
245             self.write_output_prompt()
--> 246             format_dict, md_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
247             self.update_user_ns(result)
248             self.fill_exec_result(result)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
148 
149         """
--> 150         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
151 
152     # This can be set to True by the write_output_prompt method in a subclass

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
150             return {}, {}
151 
--> 152         format_dict, md_dict = self.mimebundle_formatter(obj, include=include, exclude=exclude)
153 
154         if format_dict or md_dict:

<decorator-gen-12> in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in catch_format_error(method, self, *args, **kwargs)
215     """show traceback on failed format call"""
216     try:
--> 217         r = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
218     except NotImplementedError:
219         # don't warn on NotImplementedErrors

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
962                 return printer(obj)
963             # Finally look for special method names
--> 964             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
965 
966             if method is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/dir2.pyc in get_real_method(obj, name)
 63 
 64     try:
---> 65         canary = getattr(obj, '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_', None)
 66     except Exception:
 67         return None
```

where eventually it tries to use the `__getattr__` method! In my class I have my own defined `__getattr__` method, could this be causing a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer, and e.g. the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304092/when-i-am-in-the-python-or-ipython-console-what-is-called-when-i-am-returned-an), states in general the `__repr__` method will get called.

However, ipython searches for other special versions of the `__repr__` method to use when formatting the output, e.g., see this note to the `format` method of ipython's [`DisplayFormatter`](http://pydoc.net/ipython/5.4.1/IPython.core.formatters/) class:

```
If an object implement `_repr_mimebundle_` as well as various
`_repr_*_`, the data returned by `_repr_mimebundle_` will take
precedence and the corresponding `_repr_*_` for this mimetype will
not be called.
```

The formatter functions therefore check whether a particular method exists using the `get_real_method()` function (see [here](http://pydoc.net/ipython/5.4.1/IPython.utils.dir2/)), which calls `getattr` using a dummy method name that should not exist. In my case I had defined my class to have its own `__getattr__` method (and this is where my problems arose), which used the `hasattr` function. Due to issues with `hasattr` discussed [here](https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/) this causes problems, which in my case meant getting stuck in the `__getattr__` function. So, the moral is be very careful if you define your own `__getattr__` function as it can have unintended consequences!