# Function for array of sets return with mixed up order for some sets

Tags: python, arrays, set

I wrote a function which should return an array consisting of all possible subsets of the set {1,...,9}. The problem is not that it doesn't work - The problem is the algorithm I came up should return them "in order". What it returns however, is an array so that for the digits 8 and 9, these digits always appear in front of the indices 1, 2, 3, ... and so on and I can't grasp why it does that. Here is the function:

```
def createsubsetsamountthree(self):
        subs = []
        for i in range (1, 8):              #ranges from 1 to 7
            for j in range (i+1, 9):        #ranges from i+1 to 8
                for k in range (j+1, 10):   #ranges from j+1 to 9
                    s = set([i, j, k])
                    subs.append(s)
        return subs
```

The print statement outputs this result:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 7}, {8, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 9}, 
 {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {8, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 9}, 
 {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {8, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 9}, 
 {1, 5, 6}, {1, 5, 7}, {8, 1, 5}, {1, 5, 9}, 
 {1, 6, 7}, {8, 1, 6}, {1, 6, 9}, 
 {8, 1, 7}, {1, 9, 7}, 
 {8, 1, 9}, 
 {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {8, 2, 3}, {9, 2, 3}, 
 {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {8, 2, 4}, {9, 2, 4}, 
 {2, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7}, {8, 2, 5}, {9, 2, 5}, 
 {2, 6, 7}, {8, 2, 6}, {9, 2, 6}, 
 {8, 2, 7}, {9, 2, 7}, 
 {8, 9, 2}, 
 {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {8, 3, 4}, {9, 3, 4}, 
 {3, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 3, 5}, {9, 3, 5}, 
 {3, 6, 7}, {8, 3, 6}, {9, 3, 6}, 
 {8, 3, 7}, {9, 3, 7}, 
 {8, 9, 3}, 
 {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 7}, {8, 4, 5}, {9, 4, 5}, 
 {4, 6, 7}, {8, 4, 6}, {9, 4, 6}, 
 {8, 4, 7}, {9, 4, 7}, 
 {8, 9, 4}, 
 {5, 6, 7}, {8, 5, 6}, {9, 5, 6}, 
 {8, 5, 7}, {9, 5, 7}, 
 {8, 9, 5}, 
 {8, 6, 7}, {9, 6, 7}, 
 {8, 9, 6}, 
 {8, 9, 7}]
```

The very last set for example should be ordered as {7, 8, 9}. Even though it doesn't negatively affect the code I'm using it in - since mathematically, the listing is still correct - it still quite frankly looks crap and makes it hard to work with, it was already confusing to sort this into this pyramid like shape in the editor field here.

My question is: Why does this happen? I looked through my function again and I can't  see an issue with that, so I guess it is some weird python behavior.

I know I could get a way around this by just simply sorting the sets each, however I am curious why python doesn't seem to do this in the first place and returns me an array of sets in which for an (for me) incomprehensible reason, the 8s and 9s get returned as the first element of the set when they should always be the last.

Comment: Python `set`s are unordered. Period.

Comment: @InSync I noticed that - but I want to know WHY. I mean, it isn't completely unordered. According to that result for the range 1 to 9, in python the 8 is always the highest priority, and the number 9 has the second highest priority if there is no 1 in the set and if there is, it has a higher priority than 7. That's quite a weird pattern and I'm curious whether there is some technical reason behind it.

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70871556). This is at best an implementation detail and at worst a random result.

Comment: @InSync Okay, that answered it. Thank you very much!

Comment: [_Why don't Python sets preserve insertion order?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61414947/674039)